# SCNetworkReachability leak, even with CFRelease

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

I followed a tutorial online for finding out if the iOS device is connected to the internet. It works fine, however whenever it's called it allocates more and more memory, and it's called quite often. Also I'm using ARC, and analyzing the project comes back clean

```
 - (BOOL) connectedToNetwork {
    // Create zero addy
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Recover reachability flags
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    if(defaultRouteReachability){
       bool didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags);
       CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);

       if (!didRetrieveFlags) { 
          return NO;
       }
       BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable;
       BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired;
       return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? YES : NO;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

It seems to be allocating on the `SCNetworkFlagsReachable` and the `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress`, and even though I CALL CFRelease it still allocates more and more memory.

Comment: Are you certain this code is causing the leaks? Have you tried returning immediately from this method and checking memory allocations against when this code does run?

Comment: If I comment all the code out and return true it doesn't leak. I actually just found this ARC supported reachability replacement: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability, and so far that does not leak.

Comment: use CFRelease() outside if statement